# php regex expression to get img srcs with exceptions

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

How to write a regex expression that gets all img tags, and inside them, gets the "src" value, ignoring all the imgs tags that has a given class? 
Let's say I would like to get all srcs of img tags that don't have "dontGetMe" assigned to its classes (but may still have other classes)

i.e.

```
<img src="teste1.jpg" class="blueClass brightClass dontGetMe" />
<img src="teste2.jpg" class="blueClass" />
<img src="teste3.jpg" class="dontGetMe" />
<img src="teste4.jpg" />
```

On the example, my regex should get teste2.jpg and teste4.jpg.

The regex I got so far is the following (which gets all the imgs src values regardless of the presence of the "dontGetMe" class):

```
((?:\<img).*)(src)
```

! This regex will be used on a php script, so it has to run succesfully on "http://www.phpliveregex.com".

EDIT: The regex would be used in the following php function:
  I totally agree that regex doesn't seems to be the most clear and guaranteed way to do it, but still, my lack of php knowledge ties me with this technology.

```
function Advanced_lazyload($buffer)
{
    (...)
    $pattern = '(REGEX EXPRESSION GOES HERE)';
    $buffer = preg_replace($pattern, "$1 src='temp.gif' ImageHolder", $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: That current regex will not get you all the src values (as you say it does).

Comment: This is not a task for RegEx. Load that source into a DOM loader or BeautifulSoup (with Python). Using RegEx in your case will cause way to much trouble.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 4):

Dont use regex for parsing html. The task is for xml parser.

The **recommended** way is to use **XPath** for this.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$dox = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $dox->query('//img[not(contains(@class, "dontGetMe"))]/@src');
foreach($elements as $el){
   echo $el->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I agree on this answer as the best solution for *the problem*, yet it was not what was asked. So; agreed, but no +1 :)

Comment: RegEx will always fail here. Its not possible to provide a regex that wont fail.

Comment: if you see the problem statement, it can be directly translated to xpath query.